# Jquery issue in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do something very simple. Basically I have a clickable span, when I click that it open edit modal. I achieved this by Bootstrap modal. This works fine.

The problem is, I used a [plugin](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/) for image preview this also work as modal. When I click that span then two modals open at same time. It should not open image preview modal.

I understand the code and it happen because of 'lightgallery' class. I tried to remove that class when I click that span using jquery. It removed from html but that function already loaded from DOM. So its not working. When I click the span then two modals open at same time.

If I removed the 'lightgallery' class from html and run the system then its working fine. The problem from DOM. Please help me to solve this.

I think there's probably a much more sensible way of doing it, could someone point me in the right direction? I'd be very grateful. I've tried so many ways.

HTML code

```
<ul class="photo-grid lightgallery">
  <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" data-responsive="img/1-375.jpg 375, img/1-480.jpg 480, img/1.jpg 800" data-src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/project/1.png'); ?>" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view from Rigwood Jetty on Coniston Water an old archive shot similar to an old post but a little later on.</p>">
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"> 
     <img class="img-responsive widthauto" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/project/1.png'); ?>">
     <figcaption>
       <p>Fading Light</p>
     </figcaption>
  </a>
  <span class="editbtnprofilea nopadd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portimgmodal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>                                             
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS code

```
$("#edithire").click(function (e) {
    $('.demo-gallery>.lightgallery').addClass('lightgalleryedit'); 
    $('.demo-gallery>.lightgalleryedit').removeClass('lightgallery');  
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are initializing usin `<ul>` this would make its child `<li>` as initiators ie. clicking `<li>` or any of its member would trigger the lightgallery to show up, since your `<span>` is also a member it would too. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfrz57bv/).

To prevent this there are a few alternatives but the best one in this case is to use the `selector` option this option tells lightgallery while initialization that only those element having the given selector might be able to launch the show.

```
$({ul-selector}).lightGallery({
  selector: ".onlyme"
});
```

Now assign `.onlyme` to anchor or images that make up slide but not to the `span` that triggers bootstrap modal.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1sh8go4m/)

Comment: That was nothing, Cheers